# Generate a normal distribution within certain limits in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I would like to generate a normal distribution with a mean of 120 and a standard deviation of 20. But I need to limit the values to [0, 150]. What should I do?

```
scores <- rnorm(1000, 120, 20)
```

Comment: You can reed [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-generate-a-normal-distribution-with-mean-1-min-0-2-max-0-8-td3481450.html) where a similar problem is asked and answered.

Comment: @Etienne "I know how the generate a normal distribution of mean = 1 and sd = 1 and 
with 500 data point." made me lol so hard. Scroll down to see a solution tho!

Comment: the vectorized approach with qnorm is indeed elegant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a while loop, you can use a recursion approach:

```
foo = function(n, m, v, up, down)
{
    if(n==0) return(numeric(n))
    vec = Filter(function(x) x>=down & x<=up, rnorm(n, m, v))
    c(vec, foo(n-length(vec), m, v, up, down))
}

result = foo(1000, 120, 20, 150, 0)
```

Comment: you could remove the `l` parameter as you don't use it